# continuous integration - Cleaning up file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: django, docker

When I am trying to commit changes to gitlab for continuous integrations i am facing this error

```
Cleaning up file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am running 2 stages building and testing at the moment
here is my script for testing

```
- pytest -p no:warnings --cov=.
- flake8 .
- black --check --exclude=migrations .
- isort . --check-only
```

He is trowing this error when he went trough black and is supposed to start isort.

And what is interesting is when i am trying to run isort in the terminal his response is

```
UserWarning: Likely recursive symlink detected to /usr/src/app/env/lib
  warn(f"Likely recursive symlink detected to {resolved_path}")
Skipped 1 files
```